# read RTF files into R containing econ data (a lot of numbers)

Tags: r

Recently I obtained a lot of RTF files that contain econ data for analysis I need to do. Unfortunately, this is how Bureau of Statistics of my country could help with time series data for a long time lapse. If there is a one time need to select particular indicator for 10 years or so I'm OK to find these values by hand using Word/Notepad/TestEdit(for Mac). But my problem is that I have 15 files with data that I need to combine somehow in one dataset for my work. But, before even start doing this I don't have a clue if it is possible to read those files in appropriate format (data.frame). Wanted to ask expert opinion on how to approach this task. An example of one of files could be downloaded from here:

[https://www.dropbox.com/s/863ikx6poid8unc/Export_for_SO.rtf?dl=0][1]

All values are in Russian. Dataset represents export of particular product (first column) across countries (second column) in US dollars for 2 periods.

Thank you.

Comment: are you able to run Open Office?

Comment: Yes, I’m. What would I need it for in this case?

Comment: it can run "headless". so you could pass it (via a `system2()` call) the rtf and generate a docx and use `docxtractr` or to an HTML and use `rvest.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to manually convert your files to another format using an office suite or a text editor. You should be able to save as in another format.

While in R,  you may want to give [striprtf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/striprtf/striprtf.pdf) a try. I'm guessing you will still have to clean your data a bit afterward.

You can install the package like this:

```
install.packages("striprtf")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use code found on https://datascienceplus.com/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-simultaneously-in-r-and-create-a-data-frame/

replace read_csv with read_rtf

Comment: Welcome and thanks for adding an answer. When linking to references and example code the salient parts should be included directly in the answer.  It's easier for the asker or later readers. Links, for example, can go stale.